# How to get dynamic x and y coordinates in QPainter::translate(qreal dx, qreal dy)

Tags: qt, sqlite

I wonder if someone can help me.  I'm using a TablePrinter class found it from Github https://github.com/T0ny0/Qt-Table-Printer in my Qt project to print out some data from Sqlite database. The problem that I have is I am out putting two tables one underneath the other and I don't know how or where to start the second table from because I don't know how many rows will the first table have.
I know if I increase the 'y' value in 'painter.translate(0, 560);' it creates a gap between both tables but I need a dynamic approach not hard coded one, does anyone have any suggestions please ?
Your help would be much appreciated.
This is how I'm trying;

```
QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
printer.setPageSize(QPrinter::A4);
printer.setOrientation(QPrinter::Portrait);
printer.setFullPage(false);
QPrintDialog dialog(&printer, this);
dialog.setWindowTitle(tr("Fire Muster Report"));

if (dialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
    {
        QPainter painter;
        if(!painter.begin(&printer)) {
            qWarning() << "can't start printer";
            return;
        }

    TablePrinter tablePrinter(&painter, &printer);
    QVector<int> colStretch = QVector<int>() << 10 << 8 << 7 << 7;
    tablePrinter.setPen(QPen(QColor(0, 0, 0), 3, Qt::SolidLine)); // pen for borders
    tablePrinter.setHeaderColor(Qt::blue);
    tablePrinter.setContentColor(Qt::black);
    QFont font1; // font for headers
    font1.setBold(true);
    QFont font2; // font for content
    font2.setItalic(false);
    tablePrinter.setHeadersFont(font1);
    tablePrinter.setContentFont(font2);
    QVector<QString> headers = QVector<QString>() << "Name" << "Organisation" << "Contact No" << "Signed In";
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::blue));
    painter.drawText(painter.viewport().width()/3 - 40, 40, "Number of Visitors still signed in");
    painter.translate(0, 90); // start print point
    tablePrinter.setCellMargin(10, 7, 7, 7);
    tablePrinter.setPageMargin(100, 40, 40, 40);

    if(v != "0"){
        if(!tablePrinter.printTable(ui->tableView_visitRep->model(), colStretch, headers)) {
            qDebug() << tablePrinter.lastError();
        }
    }else{
        ui->label_visitCount->setText("No Visitors Signed In");
    }

    /***********************  Second Table  ************************/

    TablePrinter tablePrinter1(&painter, &printer);
    QVector<int> colStretch1 = QVector<int>() << 10 << 8 << 7 << 7;
    tablePrinter1.setPen(QPen(QColor(0, 0, 0), 3, Qt::SolidLine)); // pen for borders
    tablePrinter1.setHeaderColor(Qt::blue);
    tablePrinter1.setContentColor(Qt::black);
    QFont font11; // font for headers
    font11.setBold(true);
    QFont font21; // font for content
    font21.setItalic(false);
    tablePrinter1.setHeadersFont(font11);
    tablePrinter1.setContentFont(font21);
    QVector<QString> headers1 = QVector<QString>() << "Name" << "Department" << "Contact No" << "Signed In";
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::blue));
    painter.translate(0, 560); // start print point
    painter.drawText(painter.viewport().width()/3 - 0, 0, "Number of Employees still signed in");
    tablePrinter1.setCellMargin(10, 7, 7, 7);
    tablePrinter1.setPageMargin(100, 40, 40, 40);

    if(e != "0")
    {
        if(!tablePrinter1.printTable(ui->tableView_empRep->model(), colStretch1, headers1))
        {
            qDebug() << tablePrinter1.lastError();
        }
   }else{
        ui->label_empCount->setText("No Employee Signed In ");
   }
    painter.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be to use [int QSqlTableModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#rowCount).

> Returns the number of rows under the given parent. When the parent is valid it means that rowCount is returning the number of children of parent.

In your case `ui->tableView_visitRep->model()->rowCount()`